# Best way to INSERT into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

My question is more of a design question rather than code. I'm trying to `INSERT` trades on stocks, as they come in, into SQL Server.

Trades can come in many times a sec and I'm receiving trades from 15 stocks at the same time so there could potentially be a lot of trades in the same sec. My question is what is the best way to do the `INSERT`?

1. open one connection at the start of trading session and continuously insert trades as they are received will this slow down my app? The trading session is 12hrs, does SQL Server allow a connection to last that long?
2. Collect trades in memory and do `BulkInsert` once every x mins? I'd rather not keep any trades in memory as this will slow things down and use up a lot of ram ... is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A DB can handle many inserts at the same second.

Comment: Why would keeping trades in memory "slow things down".  This is an interesting assumption to me.  Typically caching and buffering are techniques which speed up programs and they involve keeping things in memory.

Comment: thank you ... @juergend so do you suggest saving trades as they arrive and there wont be any issues ?....

Comment: @Hogan my ram is limited due to cost .. i have 4GB total but after windows server and all other apps running my available drops dn to 1.25GB and that before i start my strategies ... so loading potentially millions of ticks into mem slows everything down to a halt.

Comment: @AlgoAlpha: I would open a connection to the DB and insert the data directly as it comes.

Comment: @juergend. thank you thats what im going to do .. if you want answer the question so i can mark it as answered since you were the first one .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer (and rather ambiguous due to your question), is "it depends". What it depends on is what you're using to build the client application.

If it's a web application, built with PHP/ASP, there shouldn't really be any problem with multiple inserts. SQL Server intrinsically supports this due to the way it's designed, the same goes for most RDBMS models. Of course, a bulk insert is going to have less strain, it's one operation as opposed to multiple threads of data, but 15 stocks....you're still talking about a small time operations for something that's designed to handle BIG data.

What I would probably suggest is you have an intermediate that "listens" for data, and opens a connection to the database when an transaction is in progress. In PHP we usually call this "long-polling", which is a ubiquitous term for any exchange of data that is "pushed" to and from a server. There's plenty of documentation online to help you out with this, including a Wikipedia page (if you're into that kind of stuff).

Comment: thank you for your reply .. im using a C# desktop application running on the cloud. C# should have the same latency as any other web application. so are you suggesting that i should open a new connection for every trade that is received ?? rather than open connection at start of session and just insert as they come in .. ??

Comment: Ah C# is a bit different. Have a look into websockets or open sockets, it's similar to long-polling in that it can keep a connection open for a time, and you can ask it to close after a certain amount of non activity.

Answer (score 1):

You don't describe exactly how many rows per second are being inserted. SQL Server on a good machine (whatever that means) can easily handle hundreds of sequential inserts per second depending of course on what else the machine is doing and how fast the machine/hard disks (SSDS?)/amount of memory available. So what you are asking is can someone drive from NY to California in a week?

If you find that your machine cannot handle tens or hundreds of thousand of inserts per second you may try inserting rows into a narrow table (as few narrow columns as possible ) into a table without keys. I have see SQL Server successfully handle enormous amount of inserts into such a table. I would at the end of the day copy the data into another clustered table on which I run all my processing.

Finally you may want to look at Service broker which can use messaging to handle very large volumes asynchronously.

An active connection will not time out.

Comment: thank you... i dont see inserting more than 1000 trades per sec. .. i just wanted to know if this was the best way to do it... im very new to sql

Comment: If you can batch your inserts and pass in a table of rows it will execute only a little bit slower then inserting a single row.

Comment: thank you... when you say an active connection will not time out .. does that mean that if there are no trades being inserted into the db and the open connection is just idle, that it will eventually time out ?? my connection will remain open for 5 days i will only  close it on fri 5pm ... there will be times when nothing is trading and the connection going to be idle .. will this cause a time out ?